# Submit all open files to without opening the editor

Tags: perforce

Is there a way to submit all open files to Perforce without an editor opening?

If I do

```
p4 submit
```

an editor will open with all the open files already added.  That works but I don't want an editor popping up.

If I do

```
p4 submit -i
```

I need to provide the entire changeset, including the names of all the open files.  That works but I don't want to provide the names of all the files.

I just want to submit all the open files without having to supply the list of them and without an interactive editor popping up.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with:

```
p4 submit -d <description>
```